# Is there a way to set word-breaks at suffixes and prefixes?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to tell the html or css to `word-break` a word not by individual letters but rather by suffixes and prefixes?

By setting a negative `word-spacing: -#px` i can acomplish the look of a single word that breaks where I want. The downside is that unless it is a monospace font I have to manually calculate how much `word-spacing:` I should remove. Also I don't know if that method negatively affects screen readers since it would not read it as a single word but rather as two or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you control the HTML output, you can insert [soft hyphens (`&shy;`)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) in the correct places (after prefixes, before suffixes). Soft hyphens allow a word to break up in the specified place, and will show an otherwise invisible hyphen or dash when it does. There is no way to have a browser do this automatically; you need to specify where to place soft hyphens, either manually or by running the text through some scripting or programming language.

Comment: Thanks this is the solution and actually works better than expected by adding a dash whenever the word breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed width and font you could add a dash to the word to break it. There is no other built in solution.